# dynamically add remove td cells jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mustache

I have a mustache template that gets rendered as below:

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-template">
<tr data-name="{{name}}">
    <td>
    <select id="titlesDropDown" name="SelectedTitleId"><option value="">--Select Title--</option>
    <option value="1">Mr</option>
    <option value="2">Miss</option>
    <option value="3">Mrs/Corporate</option>
    <option value="4">Dr</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td class='hidden'><input type="text" name="Other" value=""/></td>
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Age" value=""/></td>
      <td>
                <button type="button" class="removeRowBtn">
                    Remove Row
                </button>
            </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

You can see the td for the Other input field is hidden.  There can be multiple rows added to the table for adding multiple people to my DB.  I need to only show this Other TD if 'Other' is the selected field in the dropdown list.  However with remove button I am finding with the Other cell being hidden the remove button gets rendered in the cell that has table heaer of Other Title.  And then if the User selects other that class should get removed which would leave quite 'jumpy behavior.  Is there a better way to acheieve this?

I am also finding that the functionality is not quite working to remove and show the Other input text box.  My js for doing this currently is as:

```
$(document).on('change', '#titlesDropDown', function () {
    //var selectedValue = $("#titlesDropDownn option:selected").text();
 // not selecting correctly if there are multiple rows in the table   
var selectedValue = $('#titlesDropDown').closest('select').find(':selected').html();

    // if else not quite working to show hide that Other td cell
    if (selectedValue == 'Other') {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').show(); 
    } else {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `class="hidden"` on the `<td>` instead of on the `<input>`, but you are hiding and showing the `<input>`. You want to hide/show the `<input>`, not the `<td>`, so move `class="hidden"` to the `<input>`. This still does not completely fix the "jumpy" behavior.

Instead of hiding and showing the `<input>`, you could change its `visibility` style. That way you can hide it, but it will still occupy the same amount of space.

HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="Other" value="" style="visibility: hidden;" />
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
if (selectedValue == 'Other') {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').css({ visibility: 'visible' }); 
} else {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
}
```

Of course, you could also set a minimum width on the `<td>` so it would occupy the same space even when the `<input>` is hidden. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj2g9dt8/) that does that with the `<input>` in the same `<td>` as the drop-down.

Disabling/enabling, instead of hiding/showing, would be another alternative.

One more thing, if you have multiple rows with the `<select>` element, you should not give it an `id` value because then multiple elements will have the same `id`. Use `class` instead of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val) method instead of html() method:

```
var selectedValue = $('#titlesDropDown').closest('select').find(':selected').val();
```

Comment: html or text is working though - it gets me the actual string value from the select list which is what I want

Answer (score 0):

With one dropdown per row, you can't give them all the same id. Ids must be unique. Use `class="titlesDropDown"` instead.

Then

```
$(document).on('change', '.titlesDropDown', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').show(); 
    } else {
        $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input').hide();
    }
});
```